# Oracle Text Feature

Tags: oracle11g

I have a requirement to derive country from a free form string in oracle (free form string is user input and stored in a column in the database) and store this derived value.
The conditions to derive is based on either of the below scenarios:

1) The codes/country/city/zip(only for US) for the country could be anywhere in the string and on occasions, there could be more than one hit.
2) Country should be derived if a zip code (for US cities) is provided in the string (a zip-city-state lookup reference table stores this information for US).
3) country name and its corresponding 2 character country code (or ISO code) is present in the string (again stored in a lookup reference table).
4) In some cases, the country would be directly present in the input string.

Lets assume the simple case of 1 city/country input string is: DEUTSCHE BANK, UNIT NO. 123, NEW YORK

Since the string contains "NEW YORK", the country derivation is United States (based on lookup information that matches country-city).

Now, the trick is when there could be multiple hits on the string:
DEUTSCHE BANK DE, UNIT NO.123, TAIWAN

In the above string(a simple multi hit string), there are atleast 2 possibilities: DE, TAIWAN (DE corresponds to GERMANY from the lookup reference and TAIWAN is spelled out in the string).
In such cases, there must be a ranking mechanism that weights the 2 possibilities based on certain criteria: lets say, if a country is spelled out originally in the string, then it is given a higher weight than a code of a different country etc.
This choice of what needs to be given more weight can be configurable based on requirements. If later, the requirements suggest that the code is to be given a higher weight, then it should just require a meta data change to alter the weight and the result should reflect the change.

On the technical side, I have created a pl/sql code using regexp and simple string manipulations that does some of these. But, its very slow and has limitations in covering some of these scenarios and frankly, an approach that I don't like. we just wanted to get the first prototype out the door. So, we had to rush.
But, now we want to streamline the approach for performance as there are a few thousands of input rows(approx 30K) containing these input strings that come in everyday and the dervation needs to happen on the fly or atleast as a batch, but at a quicker response rate.

I was reading up about Oracle Text feature as a design approach and was pleasntly surprised by some of its features that I have been seeking. However, I am not sure where to start with this as I have not used oracle text feature before although I have started reading up on it.
Good pointers from experts would be really appreciated.

Environment: Oracle 11g.

Thanks,
Casey

Comment: Your first example is identical to your second. Why on earth does New York beat Deutsche when Taiwan doesn't? Trying to decide worldwide countries is _extremely_ difficult. Yes, you'll have to weight and doing so by offset from the end of the string is a good idea. But, for that you only need regular expressions. There's no real need to use Oracle text. We have about 5,000 lines of Python code to do this...

Comment: Hi Ben,Thanks for the response. My examples are not identical. In the first, there is no ambiguity as you only have one city (Deutsche is not a city or a country and it would not be stored this in the reference table). So, the first exmple would give you only one hit. The second example that I have provided would give you 2 hits: AG is a country code for a country that is maintained in the reference table(short form for Antigua and Barbuda) and TAIWAN which makes it a string that could produce one of the 2 countries as a result in which case, weighting is required. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: If it's comma delimited then you can split on a comma and solve that. If it's not comma delimited (and perfect) then your assumption is incorrect. The number of different spellings and misspellings of countries that come up is astronomical. For instance here's some for Angloa: angola, rep.pop. angola, republic of angola, republica de angola

Comment: Ben, it is a user input free form field (typically containing the name of the bank followed by address, but may not always follow this address rule ). Unfortunately, the separators cannot be enforced or guaranteed. 
I do agree with your assessment of misspellings and interpretations. The requirement in such cases is to programatically take the best guess 
by funnelling them through the reference list that is maintained. We will not have data maintained as Republic of Angola, but as Angola.
As long as the word angola(or its equivalent code) is present, we are good.